# Como adicionar um Form dentro de outro?

Tags: c#, winforms

Tenho dois forms (`FormMenuPrincipal` e `FormFuncionarios`) no qual quando o button `btnFuncionarios` do **Menu** for clicado, quero abrir o formulário **Funcionarios**. Pensei em adicionar um **panel** `painel` da seguinte forma:

```
private void btnFuncionarios_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FormFuncionario janela = new FormFuncionario();
    janela.Visible = true;
    painel.Controls.Add(janela);
}
```

Porém ao executar, o Visual Studio aponta o seguinte erro:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in
>   System.Windows.Forms.dll
>
> Additional information: Não é possível adicionar o controle de nível
>   superior a um controle.

O erro ocorre exatamente na linha onde estou adicionando o form dentro do painel. O que está errado ? Há outro método mais fácil de fazer isso ?

Lembrando que os dois forms citados são "normais" e eu não quero adicionar exatamente no meio, quero adicioná-lo em uma determinada área.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isso acontece porque, por padrão, um formulário é "um programa independente", que tem "domínio de si" com relação à interação com o usuário. Quando você o utiliza como parte de um outro formulário, na prática, ele deixa de ser "independente".

Você precisa sinalizar isso no controle. Então, antes de adicionar no painel, defina `janela.TopLevel = false;`.

Seu código vai ficar mais ou menos assim:

```
private void btnFuncionarios_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FormFuncionario janela = new FormFuncionario();
    janela.TopLevel = false;
    janela.Visible = true;
    painel.Controls.Add(janela);
}
```

Isso deve funcionar. Espero que ajude.

Comment: Funcionou ! Você saberia me dizer como eu faço para deixar o form ocupar todo o espaço (altura e largura) do panel ?

Comment: Acredito que seja simples, basta definir a largura e altura do form `janela` a paritr dos valores de largura e altura do panel...

Comment: Vê se isso resolve Janela..WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;

Comment: Funcionou cara, valeu ai !